# Auto Add record when Button is Pressed in Django View

Tags: django, forms, django-views

In my database, `Instrument` objects can have many `CalibrationCertificate` objects, which consist only of a ForeignKey to the `Instrument`, a date issued and a date expired. Both of these dates are automatically calculated, requiring no user input. Is there a way, therefore, that I could place a button on the `Instrument_Detail` view which would add a new `CalibrationCertificate` record to the database, with the `instrument` field set to the current object?

Comment: No, in a DetailView for Instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is IMHO the best solution. To customize url in redirect view use get_redirect_url.

views.py

```
class AddCalibrationCertificateView(RedirectView):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    url = '/instrument/1/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Here you add new certificate object, use self.kwargs['instrument_pk']
           to get related instrument
        '''
        return super(AddCalibrationCertificateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

new_cert = AddCalibrationCertificateView.as_view()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^add/certificate/(?P<instrument_pk>\d+)/$', 'views.new_cert', name='new_cert'),
```

instrument.html

```
<form action="{% url 'new_cert' 1 %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Add cert" />
</form>
```

Comment: Using method 2, how do you then render that in the template?

Comment: @RowanIngram do you mean rendering CreateView? just add template file. CBV does everything for you. Example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

Comment: No, I mean what should I do in the template to achieve the desired outcome, that is to say, a form for which all the values are auto-filled and only require the user to press 'submit'?

Comment: @RowanIngram I have updated post to what I think is the best solution